# biblatex, edit \footcite command

Tags: biblatex

I am using the biblatex package.
for my thesis I have the following requirements for a citation in the footer:

> See "last name of the author" ("year"), "pages".
>
> example footcite: See Miller (2010), p. 3.
>
> example footcites: See Miller (2010), p. 3; Martin (2008), p. 23; Matthew (2000), p. 44.

I'm using the `\footcite[pre][post]{citekey}` and `\footcites(pre)(post)[pre][post]{citekey}...[pre][post]{citekey}`command respectively but it doesn't provide the braces around the "year", everything else is fine.

I found a workaround by using `\footnote{See \textcite{citekey}, "pages".}` that generates exactly what I need but this solution is unhandy regarding punctuation.

Therefore: Is there any solution to customize the mentioned commands?
I found some similar questions here but nothing worked for me.

EDIT:
MWE:
EDIT2: Actually I use BibDesk to organise my  references, however I used the filecontents package now. Everybody should be able to compile it now.

```
\documentclass[toc=listof,12p,bibintoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{example.bib} 
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@article{example2,
Author = {Author2},
Date-Added = {2014-11-10 20:00:20 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-11-10 20:01:29 +0000},
Journal = {Journal2},
Title = {Title2},
Year = {2012}}

@article{example1,
Author = {Author1},        
Date-Added = {2014-11-10 20:00:07 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-11-10 20:01:10 +0000},
Journal = {Journal1},
Title = {Title1},
Year = {2010}}

@article{example3,
Author = {Author3},
Date-Added = {2014-11-10 19:59:11 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-11-10 20:00:40 +0000},
Journal = {Journal2},
Title = {Title2},
Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
footcite\footcite[See][p. 30]{example1}
footcites\footcites(See)(){example1}{example2}{example3}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Here an example of both commands and the output in the footer:
[image]
[image]

Everything is fine but the missing braces around the "year".

thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add some more code to make the example compilable?

Comment: What else do you need? I think I added everything necessary..

Comment: You could add a **full** [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead than snippets that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What's in `example.bib`? I cannot compile your code as it stands. `biblatex-examples.bib` is a ready-made database whose entries you could cite instead.

Comment: Can anybody help please? :/

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to me to be a very standard question, but I could not find an answer that dealt only with this problem (there were some combined answers that also incorporated this).

With the `authoryear` stle, `\footcite` uses the bibmacro `cite` (it probably does that for almost all standard styles), so we modify that to include parentheses around the year. (This will also add parentheses around the year in normal `\cite` and also in `\parencite` (not in `\textcite` though) - if you don't want that, a bit more work needs to be done.)
I also added a check to suppress parentheses if no year is present - we don't want to end up with an empty pair of parentheses, after all.

The `cite` macro becomes (with the relevant lines added and changed near the end)

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {}
       {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {}
       {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
footcite\footcite[See][30]{wilde}
footcites\footcites(See)(){companion}{knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image]